# Prism EventAggregator Exception - must be constructed on the UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, unity-container, prism

I've just revisited some very old code to update it to the latest version of Prism (Version 5) and during Module initialisation I was getting the following exception message:

```
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - To use the UIThread option for subscribing, the EventAggregator must be constructed on the UI thread.
```

Wherever I was executing something like:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppStatusMessageEvent>()
.Subscribe(OnAppStatusChanged, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
```

Changing all of these instances to:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppStatusMessageEvent>()
.Subscribe(OnAppStatusChanged);
```

Obviously fixes the issue and the app runs as normal.

How do you ensure that Unity constructs the EventAggregator on the UI Thread?

**UPDATE**

I have now added the following code to the solution in an attempt to fix this:

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    Container.RegisterType<IShellView, Shell>();

    var eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
    Container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IEventAggregator), eventAggregator);

    base.ConfigureContainer();
}
```

So this is explicitly creating the `EventAggregator` on the UI thread in my Bootstrapper and I'm still seeing the same exception being thrown about the `ThreadOption.UIThread`.

The `StockTraderRI` example project also makes use of the `ThreadOption.UIThread` and doesn't appear to do anything explicit when dealing with the `IEventAggregator` but it is using `MEF` not `Unity`.

I've been through the new Prism version 5 documentation and all I can find in there about these changes is a statement that says:

> EventAggregator now must be constructed on the UI thread to properly
>   acquire a reference to the UI thread’s SynchronizationContext.

Which I have tried in the code changes detailed above.

My Bootstrapper looks identical to all the reference implementations I can find:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the shell.
/// </summary>
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    base.InitializeShell();

    Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)Shell;
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}

/// <summary>Creates the shell.</summary>
/// <returns>The main application shell</returns>
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
}
```

I've also tried to manually resolve the `EventAggregator` immediate after the call to `ConfigureContainer` like this:

```
/// <summary>Configures the container.</summary>
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();
    var ea = Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
}
```

When looking at the `syncContext` property on the `ea` is it `null` despite that appears to be the `EventAggregator` having been resolved on the UI thread. And I'm still seeing this exception.

Has anyone seen this issue and worked out what is causing this problem?

I'm utterly stumped.

**Another Update**

So I just checked which thread this is being created on.  I derived an empty class from `EventAggregator` and put a breakpoint on the `ctor` and the thread building the class is the `Main Thread` ...

So now I'm even more confused.

Comment: which version of PRISM are you using?

Comment: Updated the question and added (version 5)

Comment: Are you subscribing the event in a different thread?

Comment: No, that's the odd thing.  There is no explicit threading going on anywhere.  It's just a small demo application, not even using any `async` or `await` keywords anywhere in the code!

Comment: can you share the demo app code?

Comment: Sure, it's all on github here, I think I've left the UIThread code in there but commented out https://github.com/jamsoft/WPF-Prism-Demo-Part1

Comment: I dont have access to Git hub here. Can you put in someotherplace.

Comment: Yup, it's here now http://www.jammer.biz/code/JamSoft.CALDemo.zip

Comment: It is giving exception. On the Application Startup. Failed to load some dependecies

Comment: Yeah, but that's because of the GetEvent call and the EventAggregator apparently not being on the UIThread.

Comment: I've added some more code to the question.  This is seriously weird.

Comment: Cracked it last night.  Seems using the StartupEventArgs ties a lot of things together in relation to the way the EventAggregator resolves the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the answer was fairly simple.

In my old code it was OK (if not ideal) to have an app class that looked this this:

```
public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        var bootstrapper = new MyBootStrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}
```

Prism 5 no longer works with this kind of initialization.  You need to initialize the application like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootStrapper = new MyBootStrapper();
        bootStrapper.Run();
    }
}
```